# Exit code to set build unstable - Jenkins DSL Scripting

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to utilize **Exit code to set build unstable** in `job` -> `publishers` -> `postBuildScripts` -> `steps` -> `shell` -> advance option to set my build unstable based on a condition.
I have the script below.

```
...
postBuildScripts {
                onlyIfBuildSucceeds(false)
                steps {
                  shell('echo "Before exit 1"\n' +
                        'if [ ! condition ]; then\n' +
                        'echo failed-condition\n' +
                        'exit 1\n' +
                        'fi'
                       )
                }
            }
...
```

On executing the above DSL script, I get as below in jenkins
[image]

With the above script `exit 1`, the build fails. But I wanted to make it unstable and I **DO NOT** want to use `markBuildUnstable(true)`. I wanted to mark build unstable based on certain exit codes only. I can do it by setting the exit code manually to 1 like below
[image]
After this, the build is marked unstable.

I'm looking for script to set this field through scripts and not manually as I have many jobs.

Can someone please help me on this with suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get this to work using the "raw" `configure` interface. When I was trying it, if I had a `steps { shell () }` anywhere else, it would overwrite and lose the settings, so I had to specify the `command` option as well. I was under the impression that `<<` would append and not overwrite, but I've never used Node before.

```
def final my_script = readFileFromWorkspace('my_script.sh') // Seed workspace
freeStyleJob("jobname") {
  ...
    configure { project ->
        project / builders << 'hudson.tasks.Shell' {
          command my_script
          unstableReturn 2
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't maintain the order of builders :(

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [Dynamic DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL):

```
job('example') {
  steps {
    shell {
      command('echo TEST')
      unstableReturn(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my local lJenkins install (2.150.3, DSL 1.71) or the Job DSL playground (1.69): http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ .  `No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.shell() is applicable for argument types: (script$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3)`

The dynamic DSL does show up in my local install (hence why I tried it). Perhaps this is a bug in the Job DSL plugin?

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much. There is no doc about this. You saved my life.